# Convert a STL mesh object outline to a path (to trace the outline of an STL)

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil, 3d-printing

I was trying to see if I could trace an outline of an STL file since it has a dense mesh and limited dissolve doesn't create a clean outline all the way around.  I was following this tutorial.
https://youtu.be/EWo7esqGy7g

1. Dense STL Mesh (**limited dissolve doesn't create a clean outline all the way around**)

[Link to file:](https://cdn.thingiverse.com/assets/52/bc/60/3c/1e/arrosoire.STL)

[image: stl mesh]

2. Convert to grease pencil

[image: grease pencil]

3. Convert to path **(But convert to path is greyed out)**

[image: greyed out]

**I was trying to avoid converting the image to a png / jpg since I would loose accuracy since this will be 3D printed and adds extra steps.  Any workarounds?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround which may help others where grease pencil isn't needed but can be used if they want to.  **Note: To use Grease Pencil `Convert To Path` it needs to be in 2D**

`2D slice (Good for copying threads from STL's to 3D print and if you want to use Grease Pencil - Convert to Path)`

```
-Center Object pivot point and / STL to Origin 
-Apply scale and Location object transform on STL / Object
-Create Mesh Plane (larger than object)
-Select Plane - Add Boolean Modifier 
    Options - Intersect
    Object  - STL or Object
    Solver  - Fast

-Hide STL / Object (allows to see 2D section)

Extra: Can Select Plane and do a G - Z to see sections
Extra Extra: Can do in Geometry Nodes
```

[image: 2D Cross section]

`3D slice (to view internals)`

```
-Same as 2D Slice but change Solver to - Exact
```

[image: 3D Cross section]